# How to find nearby hospitals using google map api and javascript

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps-api-3

```
var MapApiApplication = {
   myCurrentPosition : "",
   mapOptions : "",
   marker : "",
   initialize : function(){
      MapApiApplication.myCurrentPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(10.112293000000000000, 76.352684500000010000);
      MapApiApplication.mapOptions = {
        zoom: 13,
        center: MapApiApplication.myCurrentPosition,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      };
      MapApiApplication.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), MapApiApplication.mapOptions);
      MapApiApplication.marker = new google.maps.Marker({
         position: MapApiApplication.myCurrentPosition,
         map: MapApiApplication.map,
         title: 'Here You are'
      });
   }, 
};
```

> I have the current position's latitude and longitude. How can i find nearby hospitals locations using only javascript and google maps api.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You need to use the [Places Library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places). In the [Place Search Requests](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#place_search_requests) you can specify a `type` - which categorizes what "type" of place you are searching for. According to the [Supported Place Types by Google Places API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/supported_types), there are `hospital` and `health` types - which would probably be your best bet to get hospitals in your search response.

Comment: thank you very much for the answer. please let me know if you can provide some useful links or code for the applications like HTML5 + javascript + google map api based modules. I had gone through your profile and glad to know that you have got plenty of experience in developing these type of applications. If you can help me please provide the links or code example. Any way thanks to you

Comment: I think the sample code in the API documentation will be exactly what you need: [sample code](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/place-search). All you'll need to edit with regards to this question is the `location` and the `type` parameters in the `request`. Here's a [link to a jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/svigna/JszCD/) that I quickly put together demonstrating how it can be done.

Comment: my experience is that hospital type is extremely out of date, you are better off doing a nearby search by keyword hospital, it will give you results that are a much better match. For example we had a mayo clinic hospital near us but there were a bunch of providers with the type hospital registered in the building as well making the results inaccurate.

Comment: if you are the pure javascript guy, you can convert the typescript to javascript in this website https://extendsclass.com/typescript-to-javascript.html

Answer (score 6):

I had a chance to work on it recently.

Here is the working code snippet:

```
// comments inline
```

```js
var map;
var infowindow;

function initialize() {
  var pyrmont = new google.maps.LatLng(19.107567, 72.8335); // sample location to start with: Mumbai, India

  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), {
    center: pyrmont,
    zoom: 15
  });

  var request = {
    location: pyrmont,
    radius: 200,
    types: ['hospital', 'health'] // this is where you set the map to get the hospitals and health related places
  };
  infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
  service.nearbySearch(request, callback);
}

function callback(results, status) {
  if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      createMarker(results[i]);
    }
  }
}

function createMarker(place) {
  var placeLoc = place.geometry.location;
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    map: map,
    position: place.geometry.location
  });

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
    infowindow.setContent(place.name);
    infowindow.open(map, this);
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```css
html, body, #map-canvas {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px
}
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&libraries=places"></script>

<div id="map-canvas"></div>
```

It is **important** to note that the places wouldnt be marked onto the map if you load the  library and Javascript at the end of `<body>` tag.

Comment: How can I get all the markers that are retrieved from the map?

Comment: @JoshHarington In the `createMarker()` function, you can have the markers pushed into an array when they are created. As in `markersArray.push(marker)` The `markersArray` should be global in this case and initialized as empty array `[]`.

Answer (score 2):

Here is url to find nearby hospitals,Restaurant etc
100 % work just use it

```
url=  "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$pickupLatitudes,$pickupLongitudes&radius=1500&type=hospital&key=$googleAPIKey";
```

where `pickupLatitudes=96.766, pickupLongitudes=18.3456` something like this
type important for getting a response like =>`type=hospital,type=restaurant,type=atm`

Answer (score 0):

Here is how, you can access the JSON/XML endpoint using Google Maps API.

1. Get your API Key = $APIKey
2. Get your latitude = $latitude
3. Get your longitude = $longitude
4. Get the type of place (hospital, restaurant), etc. = $TypeOfPlace
5. Use the following URL to access the .JSON endpoint:

```
"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=$latitude%2C$longitude&radius=1500&type=$TypeOfPlace&key=$APIKey"
```

An example of a JSON endpoint is:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json
  ?keyword=cruise
  &location=-33.8670522%2C151.1957362
  &radius=1500
  &type=restaurant
  &key=YOUR_API_KEY
```

You can also make a GET Request using cURL. Example for the same is:

```
curl -L -X GET 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522%2C151.1957362&radius=1500&type=restaurant&keyword=cruise&key=YOUR_API_KEY'
```

For more information on the .JSON endpoint, please refer to the documentation: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/web-service/search-nearby